# How come TS autodetects my class declaration but not my type alias?

Tags: typescript

I have a declaration file with `export declare type Something = /**types here*/`. I'm using the type alias `Something` in another ts file.

My goal is to make TS accept `const myVar: Something = /**instance of Something*/` and not show the squiggly red line saying `Cannot find name 'Something'`--like it does for modules, classes, interfaces, and variables.

My situation:

I have this declaration file, `./declarations/Emailer.d.ts`:

```
export declare /**taking out export or declare doesn't work */ type EmailOptions = { host?: string; port?: string | number ; secure?: boolean; user?: string; password?: string; from?: string; project_id?: string | number; email_id?: string | number; }

export declare class Emailer {
    transporter: any; // Nodemailer.prototype.createTransport(options: EmailOptions)
    from: string;
    project_id: number;
    email_id: number;

    constructor(options: EmailOptions);

}
```

And the TS file, Emailer.ts:

```
const nodemailer  = require('nodemailer');

// import { EmailOptions } from './declarations/Emailer'; // It works if I add this

class Emailer {
    transporter;
    from;
    project_id;
    email_id;

    constructor(options: EmailOptions /** The 'Cannot find name' error is here */) {

        //...
}
```

How does TS autodetect my class declaration but not the type alias?

To try figuring this out, I've studied [type aliases in general](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), use of [triple directives in the path](http://%3Creference%20path=%22...%22%20/%3E), access modifiers, library structure, and declaration merging.

I suspect I'm weak on the concept of modules and namespaces in TS and will continue to study that.

I'm using TSC version 3.5.2 and VS Code 1.49.3.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you have a `.d.ts` file with the same name as a `.ts` file? It's picking up the class as a type because a class definition in a `.ts` file exports a corresponding type, why aren't you just defining the type in the `.ts` file and get rid of the `.d.ts`?

Comment: It's in `./declarations/Emailer.d.ts`. I'm new to TS, and people use declaration files, so I went with the common route. I'll think I'll do as you suggest, but I'm curious why the type alias doesn't export :o

Comment: "people use declaration files" normally you just write `.ts` files with types and code together then `tsc` compiles that to `.js` and parallel `.d.ts` files, It's not normal to use parallel `ts` and `d.ts` files. I'd link to relevent documentation but I think the typescript site is down at the moment?

Comment: there is nothing linking the declaration file to your code, you could remove the class declaration and using the class as a type would still work as you expect because it isn't using the `.d.ts` it's just using the actual class definition from the same file.